# Tensor to Dataframe for each sentence

Tags: pandas, numpy, huggingface-transformers, torch

For a 6 class sentence classification task, I have a list of sentences where I retrieve the absolute values before the softmax is applied. Example list of sentences:

```
s = ['I like the weather today', 'The movie was very scary', 'Love is in the air']
```

I get the values the following way:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer

model_name = "Emanuel/bertweet-emotion-base"
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

for i in s:
  sentence = tokenizer(i, return_tensors="pt")
  output = model(sentence["input_ids"])
  print(output.logits.detach().numpy())

  # returns [[-0.8390876   2.9480567  -0.5134539   0.70386493 -0.5019671  -2.619496  ]]
  #[[-0.8847909  -0.9642067  -2.2108874  -0.43932158  4.3386173  -0.37383893]]
  #[[-0.48750368  3.2949197   2.1660519  -0.6453249  -1.7101991  -2.817954  ]]
```

How do I create a data frame with columns `sentence, class_1, class_2, class_3, class_4, class_5, class_6` where I add values iteratively or maybe in a more optimal way where I append each new sentence and its absolute values? What would be the best way?

Expected output:

```
     sentence                   class_1        class_2    class_3      ....
0    I like the weather today   -0.8390876     2.9480567  -0.5134539   ....
1    The movie was very scary   -0.8847909     -0.9642067 -2.2108874   ....
2    Love is in the air         -0.48750368    3.2949197   2.1660519   ....  
...
```

If I only had one sentence, I could transform it to a data frame like this, but I would still need to append the sentence somehow

```
sentence = tokenizer("Love is in the air", return_tensors="pt")
output = model(sentence["input_ids"])

px = pd.DataFrame(output.logits.detach().numpy())
```

Maybe creating two separate data frames and then appending them would be one plausible way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution and I am posting it as someone might find it useful.

The idea is to initialize a data frame and to append the absolute values for every sentence while iterating

```
absolute_vals = pd.DataFrame()

for i in s:
  sentence = tokenizer(i, return_tensors="pt")
  output = model(sentence["input_ids"]) 
  px = pd.DataFrame(output.logits.detach().numpy())
  absolute_vals = absolute_vals.append(px, ignore_index = True)

absolute_vals
```

Returns:

```
     sentence                   class_1        class_2    class_3      ....
0    I like the weather today   -0.8390876     2.9480567  -0.5134539   ....
1    The movie was very scary   -0.8847909     -0.9642067 -2.2108874   ....
2    Love is in the air         -0.48750368    3.2949197   2.1660519   ....  
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the model outputs in a list and then create the dataframe from an object:

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

model_name = "Emanuel/bertweet-emotion-base"
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

outputs = []
for i in s:
  sentence = tokenizer(i, return_tensors="pt")
  output = model(sentence["input_ids"])
  outputs.append(output.logits.detach().numpy()[0])

# convert to one numpy array
outputs = np.array(outputs)

# create dataframe
obj = {"sentence": s}
for class_id in range(outputs.shape[1]):
  # get the data column for that class
  obj[f"class_{class_id}"] = outputs[:,class_id].tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame(obj)
```